# Laravel - JQuery Dropdown Display not working as expected

Tags: jquery, laravel

I am developing a project using Laravel-5.8. In the project, I am using JQuery to hide and show div.

**Controller**

```
public $rating_points = [
"1" => "Three Star Rating",
"2" => "Four Star Rating",
"3" => "Five Star Rating",
"4" => "Six Star Rating"];

public function create()
{
  return view('appraisal.ratings.create')->with('rating_points', $this->rating_points);
}

public function store(Request $request)
{        
$rating = AppraisalRating::create([
    'rating_point'               => $request->rating_point,
    'rating_type'               => $request->rating_type,
    'rating_value'              => $request->rating_value,
    'rating_description'        => $request->rating_description,
    'company_id'                => Auth::user()->company_id,
    'created_by'                => Auth::user()->id,
    'created_at'                => date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
    'is_active'                 => 1,
]);
Session::flash('success', 'Appraisal Rating is created successfully');
return redirect()->route('appraisal.ratings.index');
}
```

By default, when the form is loaded only the dropdownlist is visible as shown in the diagram:

[image: jquery dropdown]

**view**

```html
       <form  action="{{route('appraisal.ratings.store')}}" method="post" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">
           {{csrf_field()}}
                        <div class="form-body">
                            <div id='rating-point'class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group row">
                                        <label class="control-label text-right col-md-3">Rating Point<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
                                        <div class="col-md-9 controls">
                                            <select class="form-control select2" data-placeholder="Choose Rating Value" tabindex="1" name="rating_type[]">
                                                <option value="">Select point</option>
                                                @foreach($rating_points as $k => $rating_point)
                                                    <option value="{{$k}}" @if(old("rating_point") == "$k") selected @endif>{{$rating_point}}</option>
                                                @endforeach
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>  
                            </div>
                            <div class="row" id="rating-data" style="display: none;">
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <div class="form-group row">
                                        <label class="control-label text-right col-md-3">Rating Type<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
                                        <div class="col-md-9 controls">
                                            <input  type="text" name="rating_type" placeholder="Enter rating type here" class="form-control" value="{{old('rating_type')}}" readonly>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <div class="form-group row">
                                        <label class="control-label text-right col-md-3">Rating Value<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
                                        <div class="col-md-9 controls">
                                            <input  type="number" name="rating_value" placeholder="Rating Value" class="form-control" value="{{old('rating_value')}}">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <div class="form-group row">
                                        <label class="control-label text-right col-md-3">Description<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
                                        <div class="col-md-9 controls">
                                            <input  type="text" name="rating_description" placeholder="Enter rating description here" class="form-control" value="{{old('rating_description')}}">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
          
            <div id="rating-button" style="display: none;">
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">{{ trans('global.save') }}</button>
                <button type="button" onclick="window.location.href='{{route('appraisal.ratings.index')}}'" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </form>

   <script>
    $(document).ready(function($){
    $('#rating-point').on('change', function() {
      if ( this.value == '1')
      //.....................^.......
      {
        $("#rating-data").show();
      }
      else
      {
        $("#rating-button").hide();
      }
    });
    });
   </script>
```

I expect that the dropdownlist on change should determine the div tag to be displayed. This is not happening. The Divs remains hidden.

How do I resolve this?

Thank you.

Comment: this.value == '1'??? this in that case is the window element, what are you trying to do?

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia - What I'm trying to do is that if the dropdownlist is "Three Star Rating", the div where the id is "rating-data"  should be visible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've eventually solved it myself. I found out that I added id='rating-point' as

```
<div id='rating-point'class="row">
```

instead of

```
<select id='rating-point' class="form-control select2" data-placeholder="Choose Rating Value" tabindex="1" name="rating_type[]">
```

Thanks a lot @AlbertoSinigaglia